# Error Handling for input: list of int elements

Tags: python, list, function, error-handling

I am trying to error handle the input line of the numbers_list variable. But I am unsure of how to do this. I want the input to be int, space, int ..

For Example:

Enter numbers you would like to operate on seperated by space: 4 7

Or another example could be:

Enter numbers you would like to operate on seperated by space: 5 6 7 8

Here is my code:

```
def check_numbers_valid(prompt):
    while True:
        try:

            i = input(prompt))
            if i != int,'', int:
                print("This is not the correct format. Please reenter.")
            else:
                break
        except:
            print("Enter an integer.")
    return i


#game function
def game(sys):
    #input
    #turns input into list from different elements they enter
    numbers_list = list(map(int, input("Enter the numbers you would like to operate on separated by space: ").split()))
```

I am just unsure of what to put in the space 'if i != int int:' space. I know that this would not work but I have no idea know to code this as I only know how to do singular int error handling.

Thank you :)

Comment: Do the `split` and conversion to `int` in your function. If it works, the format was right, return the list of ints. if it doesn't, catch the exception, that's all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def check_numbers_valid(prompt):
    while True:
        try:
            i = input(prompt)
            [int(k) for k in i.split(" ")]
            #i.split(" ") separates i into a list of strings
            #if any of them can't be turned into an integer,
            #it will cause a ValueError
        except:
            print("""This is not the correct format. Please reenter. (correct format: 
                   integers separated by spaces)""")
            continue
        else:
            break
    return i
```

I moved the code around a bit and added something that checks whether the non-space parts of the input can be turned into a list of ints. In case it can't, it will throw an error and continue the loop. If it can, it breaks out of the loop. Hope I could help.

Comment: hello! thank you for you help. this worked. however, when i try and add elements of my list together I come across this issue. "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'". it is saying i have some fo the elements of this list in int format and some of it in string format. do you know why this is?

Comment: The `check_numbers_valid()` function still returns only what the user input was, which is always a string. If you want it to return the actual list of numbers, then changing `[int(k) for k in i.split(" ")` to `i = [int(k) for k in i.split(" ")` should do.

Comment: thank you this worked. the only problem now is that it still says it is valid if the user only enters one input. how would you solve this issue?

Comment: That seems like an edge case. To not get too messy, you can make it throw an error if the length of the input is too small. Something like `if (len(i) <= 1): raise ValueError`

Answer (score 0):

The question was a bit vague, but I hope this helps:

When you get the input from the user, it comes in the form of a string (in this case, ideally you would want numbers separated by spaces as such '1 2 3 4')

Then you can split this string, and convert each element into an integer as such:

```
i = input(prompt) # let's assume: i = '1 2 3 4'
nums = i.split(' ') # forms a list by separating on spaces: i = ['1', '2', '3', '4']
nums_list = [int(num) for num in nums]
```

If there is a data type inputed that cannot be used as int(num), the last line of code will raise a ValueError.

Hope this helped!